# Trying to use a variable from another class

Tags: java

```
public class Boss{

public void Attack1(){
    int randomspace = (int )(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
    System.out.println("Attacking space " + randomspace);
    if(space == randomspace){
        //Something right here to kill the player
    }
  }
}
```

But space is in a different class called Player

```
public class Player {
    int space = 1;
}
```

I thought about making a separate space variable and change them at the same time, but how would the Boss class know when to increment/decrement at the same time as the Player class. it would be easier to just keep it in the one class for simplicity.

**EDIT:** I figured it out. `public class Boss extends Player{` and that fixed my problem

Comment: In order to use variables in different classes use Setter and Getter methods.

Comment: Have you bothered Googling this? A cursory search reveals numerous duplicates. https://www.google.com/search?q=java+use+a+variable+from+another+class+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: I searched and drilled through the web and could not find an answer

Comment: Further to what Omore said, your Boss class knows nothing about the space variable, because it belongs to the Player class. You will need an instance of the player class to be able to get access to the Player class' space variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use parameters. (and lowercase your methods)

A boss will attack a space.

```
public void attack(int space){
    if(space == randomspace){
        //Something right here to kill the player
    }
```

If you need the Player, then you should really be using some abstract class, say `Unit`, then use `Hero` to be the main piece.

Then you can have

```
public void attack(Unit unit){
    if(unit.getSpace() == randomspace){
        //Something right here to kill the player
    }
```

And ideally  `unit.getSpace()`  could also come from some `Board` class that holds all information about the `Unit` types

Then, your logic elsewhere says `boss.attack(player)` or `boss.attack(player.getSpace())`

Comment: Fixed what? Does this answer your question?

Comment: If a boss extends Player, then you're checking if the random space is the current space of the boss?